# Speed up SELECT using ordered SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider following table:

```
| ID | COL1 |
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | xxx  |
| 3  | xxx  |
| 2  | xxx  |
| 2  | xxx  |
| 3  | xxx  |
| 2  | xxx  |
| 1  | xxx  |
```

Im using command:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=id
```

Problem is that table contains about 500 000 000 rows with 1000 different IDs and command is slow. My idea is somehow sort table by ID:

Modified table:

```
| ID | COL1 |
| -- | ---- |
| 1  | xxx  |
| 1  | xxx  |
| 2  | xxx  |
| 2  | xxx  |
| 2  | xxx  |
| 3  | xxx  |
| 3  | xxx  |
```

With sorted table it should be faster. My question is how keep table sorted? OR is there any other way how make it faster?

Comment: What you want is an index on the ID column.

Comment: Table is an unordered set of rows and SQL engine process the table not as a regular human will look for values in a very long sheet. You need to use an index or, possibly, partitioning (because the predicate still returns too much rows)

Comment: @RickJames - Correct, so I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that all there is to the table?  That is, if there are only those 2 columns, then simply add

```
 INDEX(id, col1)
```

That way you will get the optimized lookup you desire.  It still won't be fast -- it needs to shovel about 500K rows to the client.

If the table is more complex than you have shown, my suggestion may be invalid.  At least provide the complete `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I may need to suggest a rearrangement of the PK.